# PHP simple markdown parser to generate List from contents

Tags: php, laravel

as we know we have simple editor on `wikipedia` website and we can make list from content easily for example:

in my text i have this formatted text:

```
===aaa=== <--- heading one
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

====bbb==== <--- child of heading one
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb

===ccc==== <--- heading two
cccccccccccccccccc

====ddd==== <--- child of heading two as three
dddddddddddddddddd

=====eee==== <--- child of heading three
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
```

`wikipedia` can generate that to:

```
<ol>
    <li>aaa
        <ol>
            <li>bbb</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>ccc
        <ol>
            <li>ddd
                <ol>eee</ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

now i would like to implementing that like with `wikipedia`, as far its difficult  for me to understand how can i implementing that can any body help me to resolve this problem? thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any mention of `====` being an ordered list element anywhere in the markdown documentation or in the wikipedia edit sources.

Comment: @apokryfos my mean is generating list from `===`

Comment: === xxx === is a header format so technically not a list . Also you shouldn't write your own markdown parser, there's a lot already available like e.g. https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Markdown

Comment: @apokryfos yes you right, but in markdown we can't make clickable list, thats only generate simple list

Answer (score 0):

You'll have the best luck finding a 3rd party package that support markdown parsing and rendering. Here are some good examples:

https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Markdown

https://github.com/thephpleague/commonmark

https://github.com/erusev/parsedown

Comment: i dont need any markdown parser, but i want to know how can i generate list from template